# How to print msg using response::json in laravel 5?

Tags: json, laravel

I use somethink like this:

```
if(!$file_add) {
              return Response::json('Error'), 200);
        }
```

but it show somethink like this:

> [object Object]

Laravel 5

Comment: How are you seeing `[object Object]`?  Is it in your browser's console?

Comment: What's the JS code that displays the message?

Comment: http://img.nostatic.pl/img/error_55132e4209a36.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
return Response::json ([

'error' => 'errormsg'

], 404);
```